# List of bank domains to stop phish

Tags: email-spam, phishing, spamassassin, spam-prevention

I'm looking for a full list of bank domain names to include in an anti-phish routine I'm planning, does anyone have a list/URL?

Comment: dude use google for all these typo things...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd be better off with a list of phishing sites:

http://www.phishtank.com/developer_info.php